# Android: center all views by one view in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to achive. I have two views in *RelativeLayout*. **One view** is **always centred** and **stretched** if needed, **another** one is always **to left** of that view and keeps **same width**.

This is a simplified code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Single line"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/horiz"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a text"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a text"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>

    </TableLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And it looks like I wanted:

[image]

but left view behaves differently when center view is wider:

[image]

and completely gone if center view fits parent size:

[image]

### For those who are confused

That's what I'm triying to do:

if THERE IS EXTRA SPACE

- FIRST view is CENTERED
- SECOND view is TO LEFT to first

if NOT ENOUGHT SPACE

- SECOND view is LEFT CENTERED
- FIRST view takes ALL REMAINING SPACE

Can someone propose something?

Comment: add android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yourtextviewid" in horrizontalscrolview and remove android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/horiz"

Comment: Horizontal View is not centered then

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you really need `RelativeLayout` or you can either use `LinearLayout` too but I've simply changed your layout to `LinearLayout` changed the `orientation` to `horizontal` and added `android:layout_weight="1"` to `HorizontalScrollView` and everything worked fine. The full code looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Single line"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/horiz"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horiz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a text a text"
                android:textSize="17sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a text"
                android:textSize="17sp"/>

        </TableLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

As your text of TextView starts becoming longer then it takes space on the right side, wont affect left `View` and enables scrolling horizontally like this

[image: Sample]

Comment: Well, yea. I did something like that. I just set **single line** and **This is a text** to `wrap_content` and it worked fine. BUT I think it will be realy nice if **This is a text** was horizontal centered for whole parent while it could.

Comment: and where will **Single line** go ? Do you want to hide that ?

Comment: Like that: if **This is a text** width is small -- _my_picture1_, else if **This is a text** width is big -- _your_picture_.     0_o wow

Comment: hehe no you are not,you can ask whatever you like,  It's simply OK .. See the text below which is exactly centered. And the above text is showing wider because it has a long text. If it is short then it will show as your picture 1.

Comment: It is not centered. [link](http://imgur.com/bdHzdyY) And if I use `gravity=center` it wont be exact screen center

Comment: You can simply use `android:layout_marginLeft` attribute as per requirement and use `gravity = center` in parent layout not in child..

Comment: @ДмитрийКиселев Hi have you solved it ? Or still there is same issue left ?

Comment: Hi, no, I did not. I just ended with LinerLayout, but Horizontal View is still off centered. At the end, if I have enought courage, I will just center in programmaticaly with margin